# Why doesn't the "break" directive in my nginx configuration stop rewrite processing?

Tags: nginx

I have the following nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php;

    server_name _;

    if ($uri = /foobar) {
        break;
    }

    if ($remote_addr != 1.2.3.4) {
        rewrite ^ https://google.com redirect;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Whether I got to http://mydomain.tld/ or http://mydomain.tdl/foobar, I get redirected to Google.  I thought `break` was supposed to stop the processing of ngx_http_rewrite_module directives?

Comment: It is. But an `$uri` variable get changed by the `try_files` directive. Then a new loop started where `$uri` equals `/index.php`. Since I didn't see your configuration answering your question, I couldn't foresee this, sorry. Try `if ($request_uri = /foobar) { break; }` instead. Anyway, I expect additional problems with the assets.